# Stored procedure to return count

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I am trying to make a stored procedure for the query I have:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT account_number)
from account
NATURAL JOIN branch
WHERE branch.branch_city='Albany';
```

or

```
SELECT count(*)
from (
   select distinct account_number
   from account
   NATURAL JOIN branch
   WHERE branch.branch_city='Albany'
   ) as x;
```

I have written this stored procedure but it returns count of all the records in column not the result of query plus I need to write stored procedure in plpgsql not in SQL.

```
CREATE FUNCTION account_count_in(branch_city varchar) RETURNS int AS $$
   PERFORM DISTINCT count(account_number) from (account NATURAL JOIN branch)
   WHERE (branch.branch_city=branch_city); $$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Help me write this type of stored procedure in plpgsql which returns returns the number of accounts managed by branches located in the specified city.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PL/pgSQL version can look like this:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION account_count_in(_branch_city text)
  RETURNS int
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN (
   SELECT count(DISTINCT a.account_number)::int
   FROM   account a
   NATURAL JOIN branch b
   WHERE  b.branch_city = _branch_city
   );
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT account_count_in('Albany');
```

Avoid naming collisions. Make the parameter name unique or table-qualify columns in the query. I did both.

Just `RETURN` the result for a simple query like this.

The function is declared to return `integer`. Make sure the return type matches by casting the `bigint` to `int`.

`NATURAL JOIN` is short syntax, but it may not be the safest form. Later changes to underlying tables can easily break this. Better to join on column names explicitly.

`PERFORM` is only valid in PL/pgSQL functions, not in SQL functions and not useful here.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this template

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION a1()
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    return (select 1);
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
select a1()
```

Comment: `return (select 1);` can be simplified to `return ;1`

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION account_count_in(_branch_city text)
  RETURNS int AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN (
   SELECT count(DISTINCT a.account_number)::int
   FROM   account a
   NATURAL JOIN branch b
   WHERE  b.branch_city = _branch_city
   );
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```